# How to generate Odds Ratio table using Python?

Tags: statistical-significance, python, odds-ratio

I am working on a binary classification problem and am trying to do univariate analysis to get their `p-values` and `risk ratios`.

I can do this only via `IBM SPSS`? Can't it be done via `Python`?

Can someone help with this?

```
Feat1  'Yes'n (%)   'No' n (%)       RR      95% CI       P
Feat2   43 (72.9)   822 (8.4)       28.0    15.9-49.6   <.001
Feat3   11 (18.6)   721 (7.3)       2.87    1.50-5.50   .004
Feat4   18 (30.5)   1,654 (16.8)    2.16    1.24-3.75   .008
Feat5   31 (52.5)   3,679 (37.4)    1.84    1.11-3.07   .02
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any python tools which can yield this table exactly.  You'd likely have to code it up yourself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it cannot create the table in exactly how you specified, you can calculate risk ratios (and other measures) using the [zEpid](https://github.com/pzivich/zEpid) library. This library supports both calculating from summary counts (details [here](https://zepid.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Reference/Calculations.html#measures)) and directly from pandas `DataFrame` objects (details [here](https://zepid.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Reference/Measures.html#id1)).

The library does not directly calculate p-values, but you can easily do this by a little extra code. Below is a quick example and code snippet for the pandas `DataFrame` object

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import norm
from zepid import RiskRatio

# creating an example data set
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['A'] = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
df['B'] = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]

# calculating risk ratio
rr = RiskRatio()
rr.fit(df, exposure='A', outcome='B')

# calculating p-value
est= rr.results['RiskRatio'][1]
std = rr.results['SD(RR)'][1]
z_score = np.log(est)/std
p_value = norm.sf(abs(z_score))*2
```

You can easily generalize this by using the following function

```
def calculate_pvalue(data, exposure, outcome):
    rr = RiskRatio()
    rr.fit(data, exposure=exposure, outcome=outcome)

    # calculating p-value
    est = rr.results['RiskRatio'][1]
    std = rr.results['SD(RR)'][1]
    z_score = np.log(est) / std
    p_value = norm.sf(abs(z_score)) * 2
    return est, p_value
```

**Disclosure:** I am the creator of this library. I don't have p-values directly calculated to discourage the misuse of statistical significance. I would recommend reporting confidence intervals over p-values, since they provide more information than a p-value.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Upvoted. Will try and update the answer tomo without fail. If not, you can leave a comment here.

Comment: Hi, how do I get the `confidence interval` from your sample code?

Comment: Running `rr.summary()` will print all the different measures calculated to the console. To access those items, you can use `rr.results`. The lower CL is `rr.results['RR_LCL']` and the upper is `rr.results['RR_UCL']`

Comment: @pzivich hey, could you check this post ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/70778082/5893454 I'm using your package to deal with risk ratios, but with no success (yet). Thank you!